# Implode using glue from an array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Is there any method i can turn this array

```
array( 'username' => array('value'=>'value1', 
                           'glue'=>' OR '),
'username' => array('value'=>'value2',
                    'glue'=>' OR ')
);
```

into

```
username='value1' OR username='value2' OR
```

I would appreciate your help...

Comment: you could try foreach, but considering its not a valid array, I doubt it will work, array keys are unique, just FYI... So it's unlikely you will get an array with two keys of `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$string = "";

$myArray = array( 
  'username1' => array(
    'value'=>'value1', 
    'glue'=>' OR '),
  'username2' => array(
    'value'=>'value2',
    'glue'=>' OR ')
);

foreach ($myArray as $key => $keyValue)
{
  $string .= $key."='".$keyValue['value']." ".$keyValue['glue']." ";
}

echo $string;//printing the results
```

Let me know it that helped!

Comment: array keys are unique, so how can you have two keys of `username`... Just curious.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix you are correct, I had just copy pasted his array without double checking it's composition. Answer has been edited.

Comment: Oh so that was the problem, the array keys have to be unique
Well i guess it wont work in my case...